# Preserving section counters after part

Tags: beamer, counters

I need to separate my lecture notes in beamer week by week by using \part without losing the section/subsection/subsubsection counters from the previous parts.
I can manually set the counters by hand, but there must be a better solution.

I would be very glad if you can help me in this direction.

Thank you.
bkarpuz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, the third overall section is the first section in the second part, but it gets the section number "3", independently from the part counter:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \begin{frame}
    \sectionpage
  \end{frame}%
}

\AtBeginPart{%
  \begin{frame}
    \partpage
  \end{frame}%
}

\begin{document}
\part{First part}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\part{Second part}
\section{Third section}
\end{document}
```